# Are Swift segues closely coupled?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller, segue, coupling

In Swift using MVC a common way to send data forward is to use `prepare(for:sender:)`. Inside that method you get a reference to the destination VC and access its properties to send the data. But isn't that considered coupling the view controllers? I'm hoping the answer isn't considered a matter of opinion because I'd really like to understand how segues fit into MVC.

Comment: I am relatively new to this so open to correction, but I thought decoupling referred to the separation of the data model from the view and view controllers (like MVC) rather than whether two view controllers are closely related. Passing data this way (provided it is only the data and not view state etc) should be fine. This is especially true if using value types as opposed to reference types (I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing data in a *segue* is completely compatible with MVC.  The destinationVC is considered as a *View* of the sourceVC.  When a controller communicates with a *View*, it configures the *View* with the data it needs.  Writing to the public interface (properties) of the destinationVC is how you set it up.  This is what is happening in `prepare(for segue:sender)`.

The concern about *coupling* relates to *reuse*.  The more tightly coupled the viewControllers are, the harder it is to reuse them.  This is only a problem if the `destinationVC` knows details of the `sourceVC`.  If the `destinationVC` needs to pass data back to the `sourceVC`, it should do so using *delegation* (where a *protocol* is used to define the methods that the *sourceVC* implements).

Comment: To put it another way (I don't want to add another answer, since this is so well put), it is quite usual for the source VC to know the identity and properties of the destination VC, because the source VC is the one effectively ordering the destination VC to come into the VC hierarchy, and will live longer — in a very real sense, the source is the master while the destination is the servant. But the destination VC should not usually know anything directly about the source VC.

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with you here. Casting a destination to a specific class of object **is** tight coupling. (Of course that's not necessarily a bad thing.) You can instead use protocols to make the coupling looser. See my answer for a more loosely coupled solution.

Comment: @DuncanC, I never said they weren't tightly coupled, only that the reason anyone worries about that is for reuse reasons.  A segue is wired to a specific destination controller, so the source controller knows what its type is.

Answer (score 2):

If view controller A segues to view controller B and assumes it is of type `ViewControllerB` then yes, that is tight coupling:

```
prepare(for: segue, sender: sender) {
   if let viewControllerB = segue.destination as? ViewControllerB {
      viewControllerB.property = value
   }
}
```

That code only works if the destination is a specific class, `ViewControllerB`, and the first view controller has to know the properties of `ViewControllerB`.

That's not usually a problem because usually when you segue to another view controller you know what you've asked for, and hence what to expect.

However, you might use the same `prepare(for:sender:)` method to segue to any of several different types of view controllers that have common properties.

In that case you can use protocols to make the coupling looser:

### Approach 2: Loosely coupled using a protocol

```
protocol DestProtocol {
  var property: String
}
```

You might have a `ViewControllerB` that conforms to `DestProtocol`

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController, DestProtocol {
   var property: string
   //The rest of ViewControllerB
}
```

And you might **also** have a `ViewControllerC` that conforms to `DestProtocol`

```
class ViewControllerC: UIViewController, DestProtocol {
   var property: string
   //The rest of ViewControllerC
}
```

Then in the first view controller's `prepare(for:sender:)`:

```
prepare(for: segue, sender: sender) {
   if let destination = segue.destination as? DestProtocol {
      destination.property = value
   }
}
```

With the second approach the first view controller's `prepare(for:sender)` doesn't know that the destination is an instance of `ViewControllerB`. It just checks to see if the destination conforms to the `DestProtocol`. The segue could be loading an instance of `ViewControllerB` or `ViewControllerC`.